# Symbol is lost after linking shared library

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

Consider the two files listed below:

file `a.c`

```
extern int foovar;
int foobarize() {
    return foovar * foovar;
}
```

and file `b.c`

```
int foovar = 10;
```

I compile the static library `liba.a` and the shared library `libb.so` as follows:

```
# liba.a
gcc -fPIC -c a.c -o a.o
ar cr liba.a a.o
ranlib liba.a

# libb.so
gcc -fPIC -c b.c -o b.o
gcc -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libb.so -o libb.so b.o liba.a
```

Note that the function `foobarize` defined in `a.c` *is* present in `liba.a` but it *isn't* present in `libb.so`. I can guarantee that by issuing the `nm` program:

```
$ nm liba.a

a.o:
0000000000000000 T foobarize
                 U foovar
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_

$ nm libb.so
000000000020088c B __bss_start
000000000020088c b completed.6617
                 w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000000530 t deregister_tm_clones
00000000000005c0 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000200650 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000200880 d __dso_handle
0000000000200660 d _DYNAMIC
000000000020088c D _edata
0000000000200890 B _end
0000000000000630 T _fini
0000000000200888 D foovar
0000000000000600 t frame_dummy
0000000000200648 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
0000000000000640 r __FRAME_END__
0000000000200858 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 w __gmon_start__
00000000000004d8 T _init
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000200658 d __JCR_END__
0000000000200658 d __JCR_LIST__
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
0000000000000570 t register_tm_clones
0000000000200890 d __TMC_END__
```

How can I get the `foobarize` function in the `libb.so` shared library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need:

```
# force all symbols

gcc -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libb.so -o libb.so b.o \
           -Wl,--whole-archive liba.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive

#force just a specific symbol

gcc -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libb.so -o libb.so b.o \
           -u foobarize liba.a
```

Why you need it:

A static library is a simple collection of object files. The one major difference from a bunch of object files is the following: when an undefined symbol needs to be resolved, the library is searched *and only the object file that actually defines the symbol is linked*. No undefined symbols? Nothing is searched, nothing is linked. To override this default behaviour, the GNU linker implements `--whole-archive`. Most linkers implement `-u` to force a particular symbol to be treated as undefinmed.

Comment: See also http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html and http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking/